# Transpose and reshape - is there a more elegant / relevant way to do the following?

Tags: matlab

Here I am trying to multiply the r g b data of this image by a 3x3 matrix.

```
fil=size(image,1);
col=size(image,2);
N = fil * col;
primaries = reshape(image, N, 3);
primaries = primaries';

% modification

primaries = primaries';
result = reshape(primaries, fil, col, 3);
```

Comment: Well, you could add the transpose into the `reshape` line, if that helps any. Anything beyond that depends on what you're doing in `% modification`.

Comment: Thank you beaker. I'm multiplying the r g b data by a 3x3 color matrix transform to change the gamut of the image. I would have thought there's a simpler way to do that by taking the image file in it's normal form of x by y by color format and multiplying it by the 3x3 matrix using indexing like [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1] * image(:,:,1);. Forgive my novice question!

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me. Maybe somebody else will have a better idea.